# Wix heat for per machine installer

Tags: wix, installation, wix3.5, heat

I use the following command to create a `wxs` file for class registry, using `heat`:

```
"C:\Program Files\Windows Installer XML v3.5\bin\heat.exe"   
    file MyAddin.dll -ag -template fragment -out MyAddin.wxs
```

The result is registry entries per user. In the following lines from the created `wxs` file you can see `HKCU` -- for `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`:

```
<Class Id="{1AF5E2B9-CC02-368F-A879-1DF3F538D71A}" Context="InprocServer32"
       Description="AdminAddins.MyClass" ThreadingModel="both"
       ForeignServer="mscoree.dll">
     <ProgId Id="AdminAddins.MyClass" Description="AdminAddins.MyClass" />
</Class>  

<File Id="fil08256E64C10A4B2F5423A768ECB9A473" Name="AdminAddins.dll"
      KeyPath="yes" Source="..\AdminAddins\bin\Release\AdminAddins.dll" />
<RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="\CLSID\{1AF5E2B9-CC02-368F-A879-1DF3F538D71A}\Implemented Categories\{62C8FE65-4EBB-45e7-B440-6E39B2CDBF29}"
               Value="" Type="string" Action="write" />
```

How should I change the command so that the file contains values for a "per machine" installer?

Comment: Don't know for sure, but my first instinct is to use `Root=HKLM` (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE).

Comment: @EricBrown, Thanks. Where should I set the root? In the class element?