# InstallScope="perMachine" in wix makes no difference

Tags: wix, windows-installer, installation

Hi i need my application just to work in administator mode and all users mode.(ie)It should work in all the modes.
I have created setup in **WIX** and after surfing a lot i came to know that setting **InstallScope="perMachine"** in package makes our application work in all the modes. But i found that only it shows our application under **Add\Remove programs** in all logins(admin or other users).

**(ie)**: I am able to work my application in administrator mode and if i logged in as any user then my application is not visible for working.Its just appears in **Add\Remove programs**.

**My requirement is i need my application work in all the mode,administrator,logins,all users too.**

```
 <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" ></Package>
```

Even i tried allUser option in InstallScopeDlg.
I need my application should work for all users including administrator too

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "application" in your question.  Does it mean the "application being installed", or does it mean the "installer package"?  Which version of WIX are you using?

Comment: Actually using wix 3.8 ..!! Application been installed and its setup was made by wix

Comment: What does this mean "my application is not visible"? And "not visible for working"? You mean you've installed it and... you can't see the files? You can't see shortcuts?

Comment: @PhilDW yes excatly..can't see the files ,cant able to use too .Actually its an addin for a software

Comment: @bradfordrg  
Actually using wix 3.8 ..!! Application been installed and its setup was made by wix

Comment: Again, you'll need to supply more detail, but it sounds like your setup installs to a location where limited users don't have write access. If you installed to ProgramFiles it could end up in C:\ProgramData, as an example.

Comment: @PhilDW what details needed please let me know .!!!

Comment: As I said, if you are installing the ProgramFiles or any other similar location that a limited user cannot write to, then you will redirect to C:\PrtogramData.  So where are the files being installed to?

Comment: @PhilDW FIles being written into programFiles

Answer (score 6):

In the Setup.wxs file add the following line

```
<Property Id="ALLUSERS" Value="1"></Property>
```

The file should look like :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>  
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
<Product Id="*"
         Name="programName"
         Language="1033"
         Version="1.0.0.0"
         UpgradeCode="183CC369-D86F-43B3-99E7-A82A16335E52"
         Manufacturer="CompanyName">
    <Package Description="#Description"
             Comments="Comments"
             InstallerVersion="200"
             Compressed="yes"/>
    <!--
        Source media for the installation. 
        Specifies a single cab file to be embedded in the installer's .msi. 
    -->
    <Media Id="1" Cabinet="contents.cab" EmbedCab="yes" CompressionLevel="high"/>

    <!-- Installation directory and files are defined in Files.wxs -->
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir"/>

    <Feature Id="Complete"
             Title="programName"
             Description="programName"
             Level="1">
        <ComponentRef Id="programNameFiles"/>
        <ComponentRef Id="programNameRegEntries"/>
    </Feature>

    <!--
        Using the Wix UI library

        WixUI_InstallDir does not allow the user to choose 
        features but adds a dialog to let the user choose a 
        directory where the product will be installed
    -->
    <Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR">INSTALLDIR</Property>
    <Property Id="ALLUSERS" Value="1"></Property>
    <UIRef Id="WixUI_InstallDir"/>
</Product>
```

Comment: @dahsra, of course do not forget to speify the regsitry keys in Files.wxs to  `HKLM` which means Local Machine.

Comment: will you please tell me what would it do if we set this <Property Id="ALLUSERS" Value="1"></Property>

Comment: @dahsra, It makes the the Wix installer know that you would like to install for all users  (per machine).

Comment: @dahsra, This is another question. I answer here the question you asked here. Please vote. I'll take a look there.

Answer (score 1):

The Program Files folder cannot be updated by limited users. Just because you have a per machine install doesn't mean that Windows Installer will violate the security rules by allowing limited users to write there!

The most likely thing that is happening is that admins install successfully to Program Files because they have the privileges to do that. Limited users cannot write to Program Files, so the files get diverted, most likely to C:\ProgramData

When you say "the app is not working" for limited users I'll guess that it may be a security issue - it needs admin privilege because it tries to write/update restricted locations or registry entries. In other words your app will only work for limited users if it restricts its activities to those permitted to limited users.  If the app is not working then debug it - it's impossible for anyone here to say why it's failing without a lot more information. That's an app issue, not an install issue.